# Add a request header through the event: page.resource.requested in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I tried (without success) to add a custom header to the request through the event:

```
 casper.on("page.resource.requested",function(requestData,request){...}
```

***something like that:***

```
casper.on("page.resource.requested",function(requestData,request){

     request.setHeader("X-myHeader", "123");
}
```

I thought I could do that because in PhantomJS you could write:

```
 page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
      networkRequest.setHeader("X-myHeader", "123");
 }
```

What are my options to add a request header during that event (of the `casper` object)?

Comment: Btw, with what version of phantomjs did your last snippet work?

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Comment: confirmed that this works in version 2.0.0

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version 1.9.7, there is a bug [request in onResourceRequested has no setHeader function #12264](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12264). You need to use an earlier version of phantomjs.

The difference arises because you use a different version of phantomjs on the commandline and in casperjs. In windows you find casper's phantom in this folder:

```
C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\casperjs\node_modules\phantomjs
```

The two easiest actions you could do is, either

- add the working phantomjs that you can use to your PATH (casper will use it)

  *OR*
- overwrite the executable inside `casperjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom` with the working phantomjs version

  *OR*
- just let npm download the version for you

The steps for that last point are:

1. Find out which version of phantomjs it works with by calling `phantomjs --version` from commandline
2. Change into the following folder in commandline

   ```
   C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\casperjs
   ```
3. Install your working version (I don't actually know which one works, so I use 1.9.0 here)

   ```
   npm install phantomjs@1.9.0-x
   ```

   You can check what version are available by calling `npm show phantomjs`.